# How to import moment-precise-range-plugin in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, momentjs

I am trying to use moment-precise-range-plugin to find the difference between the two dates. So, I tried importing packages likes this in React

```
import moment from "moment";
import "moment-precise-range";
```

And then, I tried to use this in my code

```
console.log(moment.preciseDiff(endDate, startDate, true));
```

I am getting this error
**Uncaught TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).preciseDiff is not a function**

I definitely understand the problem is with the import only. How do I import it correctly?

References :

[moment-precise-range-plugin npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-precise-range-plugin)

[Moment.js precise-range plugin](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/preciserange/)

Answer (score 1):

From the DOCS:
To use the plugin within a node.js application, add the following require statement into your code:

```
require('moment-precise-range-plugin');
```

Or:

```
import 'moment-precise-range-plugin';
```

The problem here is that you are missing the string '-plugin' in the import statemnt...